# Facing Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
public class Locators {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\ComprehendDTP\Chrome driver Jars\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/locatorspractice/");
    }
}
```

how to resolve this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslashes as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ComprehendDTP\\Chrome driver Jars\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Or use forward slashes:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/ComprehendDTP/Chrome driver Jars/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe");
```